# Replacing entries in one column by another based on condition

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have a slightly complicated problem today. I have a data frame (df) with three columns:

```
   ID    Organization   org
   1     Company1       company1
   2     Company1       company1
   3     Company2       company2
   4     Company2       company1
   5     Company2       NA
   6     Company3       company3
   7     Company3       demo
   8     Company4       company4
```

I want to create a new column called "org_corrected" with the following condition:

If entry in "Organization" and "org" is the same then "org_corrected" must be equal to entry in "Organization"

If entry in "Organization" and "org" is not same and "org" not equal to "demo" and "NA" then org_corrected" must have entry of org (first letter capitalize")

Expected output:

```
   ID    Organization   org          org_corrected
   1     Company1       company1     Company1
   2     Company1       company1     Company1
   3     Company2       company2     Company2
   4     Company2       company1     Company1
   5     Company2       NA           Company2
   6     Company3       company3     Company3
   7     Company3       demo         Company3
   8     Company4       company4     Company4
```

I can do this easily in excel, but want to do this in R.

Thanks in advance, you guys/girls have always solved my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ifelse`

```
df1$org_corrected <- with(df1, 
        ifelse(toupper(Organization)==toupper(org)|is.na(org)|org=='demo', 
                            Organization, org))
```

If we need to change the case of some entries 'org_corrected`to`camelcase` (i.e. from 'org')

```
library(rapport)
df1$org_corrected <- tocamel(df1$org_corrected, upper=TRUE)
```

Comment: I had a feeling, that you would be the first one to reply and solve this, thanks a lot akrun., but my question is will this handle the case mismatch, "org" is lower case while "organization" is sentence case

Comment: @user3875610  I just happened to login at this time.

Comment: @user3875610 I just noticed that the `Organization` and `org` have difference in case for the first letter.  Is that a typo?

Comment: @user3875610  In that case we can convert to a common case and then compare i.e. `toupper` added in the code.

Comment: i agree with the logic but, org_corrected is filled with numbers ( 1,2, 3, 10) after running the code

Comment: @user3875610  I guess your columns are `factor` Convert to `character` and it should work.  i.e. `df1[2:3] <- lapply(df1[2:3], as.character)`